# How I can connect module GSM SIM800L?

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-nano, gsm

I bought a GSM module, and I want to connect it with Arduino but I have a problem.

I linked GSM SIM800L with regular LM2596 12 V 2 VA I changed tension to 5 V, So far the GSM is working but if I connect TX_ARDUINO with RX_GSM the module enters in the loop of the restart.

The picture explains the montage.

[image: Fritzing of LM2596, SIM800L and Arduino Uno]

Comment: How are you providing power to arduino?

Comment: I connect Arduino with my pc.

Comment: And your code...?  Also, you shouldn't be using GSM in modern designs. Many carriers are turning off GSM services. You should be using (at least) an LTE modem.

Comment: You should separate the ground of external power supply and GND of arduino.

Comment: @Vaibhav How is that going to help matters? All that will do is break things further.

Comment: @Vaibhav  how I can do it ??

Comment: @ÀbdóBougaà your module must have gnd terminal use it for supply as well.

Comment: @Majenko what I think Hardware connections are not right.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Arduino Sim800l]

Follow [this tutorial](https://www.teachmemicro.com/arduino-sim800l-tutorial/) on how to connect your Sim800l with Arduino.